# How can I store thumbnails for videos I upload on AWS at the same time in nodejs without lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, fluent-ffmpeg

I am working on thumbnail creation with **ffmpeg**. I have successfully created thumbnail for uploaded video on AWS.

For upload video/videos I have flow like:

- I have one API used for multiple type file uploading. Also I have used upload.array to pass multiple file at the same time.
- This API is called by Front-end developers to get the Uploaded files detail:
  Response of that API is like:
  `

  ```
  {
   "success": true,
   "message": "Files uploaded successfully",
   "data": [
       {
           "fileName": "1628503061631.mp4",
           "mimeType": "video/mp4"
       }
   ]
  }
  ```
- This file name I receive in **request.body** whenever Edit/Add Post media API will be used also it will be stored in DB table too.
- I have configured ffmpeg as per this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vue0_vs2AI
- The problem I am facing is, I am not able to **upload thumbnail along with video upload**
- After video is uploaded in S3, that time only I am able to get its location and I create thumbnail from that.

Is there any way to give AWS S3 path direct to the second argument of the **Thumbnail function?**

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
var ffprobe = require('ffprobe-static');
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobe.path);

...
 ffmpeg({ source: req.files[k].location })

 .on('filenames', (filenames) => {
     console.log("Created file name", filenames);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
  return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Files uploaded successfully",   data: uploadedMedia })
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
     console.log("Error", err);
  })
  .thumbnail({
    filename: 'thumbnail_' + req.files[k].key.split('.')[0],count: 1
    }, './uploads/thumbnails/<<HERE I WANT TO ADD S3 path');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works perfect for making thumbnail from videos and upload it to S3.

```
ffmpeg({ source: 'location of the file' })
.on('filenames', (filenames) => {
   // created an array of thumbnail files as I have multiple media upload
})
.on('end', () => {
   for (let i in arrayofthumbnailfiles) {
       const uploadFile = () => {
           filePath = 'path where I have stored my thumbnails before s3 upload'
           const params = {
              Bucket:// pass your bucket name
              Key: // pass your key name,
              Body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
              ContentType: // media content i.e. png,
              ACL:// add ACL value here
           };
           // here I have uploaded thumbnails in s3
           s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
           if (s3Err) throw s3Err
           if (data) {
              // Unlink file - removed from local storage
           }
         });
       };
    uploadFile();
   }
  })
 .on('error', (err) => {
     console.log("Error", err);
  })
.thumbnail({filename: //set your filename here,count: 1}, 'localstorage path you want to save thumbnails temporary');
```